# Combinatorial interpretation of factorization identity

Tags: combinatorics, functions, divisibility

For $a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}$, it is the case that $a^{bc}-1=(a^b-1)(1+a^b+a^{2b}+\cdots+a^{b(c-1)})=(a^c-1)(1+a^c+a^{2c}+\cdots a^{c(b-1)})$. It is perhaps slightly more suggestive to write this as $a^{bc}-1=(a^b-1)\displaystyle{\sum_{n<c}a^{bn}}=(a^c-1)\displaystyle{\sum_{n<b}}a^{cn}$

On its own, this identity gives factorization information about natural numbers of this specific form. For example, $63=2^6-1=(2^2-1)(1+2^2+2^4)=3\times 21=(2^3-1)(1+2^3)=7\times 9$.

**My question is:** Is there a way to understand this factorization in terms of functions? The total number of functions $f:b\times c\to a$ equals $a^{bc}$, so the number of *non-zero* functions is $a^{bc}-1$. As a special case, we can take $a=2$ to interpret things as subsets so that the number of non-empty subsets $\varnothing\subsetneq X\subseteq p\cdot q\in\mathbb{N}$ is equal to $2^{pq}-1=(2^{p}-1)\displaystyle{\sum_{n<q}2^{p\cdot n}}$.

Evidently, the non-empty subsets of $p\cdot q$ correspond to first picking a non-empty subset of $p$ and then picking $n<q$ along with an arbitrary subset of $p\cdot n$. And moreover, this is symmetric in $p$ and $q$. However, I cannot figure out how this actually works out. I have tried writing out a $p\times q$ rectangle for small $p,q$ but the non-empty subsets don't seem to have any obvious properties that split into the necessary factorization (that I can find). In particular, I am having a hard time understanding how the quantity $\displaystyle{\sum_{n<q}a^{n\cdot q}}$ might be given a combinatorial interpretation in the context of functions into $a$.

Thanks!

Edit: Thanks to Mike for the idea to consider which is the rightmost column not all zeros. I realized it's the same thing to consider $\displaystyle{\sum_{k<n}2^k}=2^n-1$ by the correspondence $(k\in n,X\subseteq k)\mapsto (\varnothing\subsetneq  X\cup\{k\}\subseteq n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a^{bc}-1$ is the number of $b\times c$ grids ($b$ rows, $c$ columns) of numbers, each of between $0$ and $a-1$, such that not all the entries are $0$.

$(a^b-1)\cdot a^{bn}$ is the number of binary grids where rightmost nonzero column is column number $n+1$. There are $a^{bn}$ ways to fill the leftmost $n$ columns arbitrarily, then $a^b-1$ ways to fill column number $n+1$ so it is not entirely zero, and then the remaining columns are forced to be zero.

Summing the last quantity over $n=0$ to $c-1$, you get all possible nonzero grids. Of course, these can be thought of as functions from a set of size $bc$ to a set of size $a$.